# MySQL Select values in table depending on another table

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a table 'Staff' with details of all Staff. 'StaffID' included.

Then I have a table 'StaffRole' which has 'StaffID' and 'RoleID'

I want to do something like this: `Select * From Staff Where RoleID=1;`

But I'm not sure if I can do this as RoleID is not in the Staff table.

Anyone know the correct syntax? Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can an SQL query return data from multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM staff s
WHERE EXISTS(
   SELECT 'ROLE'
   FROM staffrole r
   WHERE r.staffid = s.staffid
   AND r.roleid = 1
)
```

In alternative:

```
SELECT * FROM staff s
JOIN staffrole r
ON r.staffid = s.staffid
WHERE r.roleid = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a join:

```
select s.*
from staffrole r
join staff s
  on s.staffid = r.staffid
where roleid = 1
```

An index on `staffrole(roleid)` should make it perform better.